# How do I make sure I do not die?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

In the game, Pixel Dungeon, your goal is to get to the bottom floor and grab an amulet, and bring it back to the top. But, when ever I try, I tend to die at around floor 10-15 due to inadaqute equipment and potions. What should I be doing to make sure I have the highest survivablity?

I mainly play as Warrior (with Gladiator sub class). I can play as anyone but the Huntetress (?), but I have no sub classes for the other characters.

Comment: Have you tried simply not playing the game?  I believe that would solve your dying problems...

Comment: But, but, video games D:

Comment: it says to unlock huntress, you need to slay the 3rd boss with any other class

Comment: I know, the only time I got to floor 15, I got wrecked by the robot boss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixel dungeon is about good position when fighting enemies and correct use of the limited resources.

Try to identifie as soon as possible all potions and scrolls, try them out in a closed chamber on top of water in case you junk down a flame potion.

Save your upgrade scrolls for better equipment, if by floor level 7-8 you havent gotten a better armor than leather then spend some of them on your armor.

As a gladiator you favour fast weapons (mace and fist) if you get one early spend your upgrade scrolls only on that weapon.

Always focus with your scrolls it is better to have a bit inferior weapon tier with more upgrades than a higher tier weapons withouth upgrades.

try to fight in narrow passages and behind doors so you only face 1 enemy at once and you get the bonus acuracy and damage from first hit from behind door.

As a warrior treasure the food you find, it is better to get to the starve condition get some damage and then eat the food it will heal you some hp.

if you have a heavier amor that you cant use because of strenght requeriment, if there is a fight you can change into it and let the enemy come, if you dont move you dont consume extra stamina.

try to be always at the same level than the floor you are in.

you can farm potions with bats and flies, unequip your weapon and try to hit the flies in a open space

have your drew drop vial always maxed out in case of emergency.

can't think of more tips

For more info oficial wiki: http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: One thing, what should I classify as better equipment? Should I settle for 1 tier up, or should I wait for something higher?

Comment: I imagine you were talking about the "by floor level 7-8",armor tiers go from lowest to highest cloth<leather<chain<scale<plate. Due to the game randomess i can't exactly answer your question, sometimes you are lucky and find an positive enchanted (cursed or uncursed) scale armor in floor leve 1 and sometimes until floor level 10 you dont see any armor, the game tends to reward properly taking into account the character level and the floor level.
That is the reason I recomend to have the same level or more than the floor so the rewards scale into your favor